# Вывод сложного массива

Tags: php

Я новичок в php. Подскажите что я делаю не так. Есть массив items, который имеет следующую структуру

```
Array
(
    [FIELDS] => Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 58892
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 58893
            )
    )

    [PROP] => Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [DOMAIN] => Array
                    (
                        [SORT] => 1
                    )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Пытаюсь вывести содержимое следующих полей, но ничего не получается

```
foreach($items as $k => $v){
var_dump($v["FIELDS"][$k]["NAME"]);//NULL

    echo $v["FIELDS"][$k]["ID"];
    echo $v["PROP"][$k]["DOMAIN"]["SORT"];    
}
```

Comment: у вас `$k` в цикле меняет значения `fields` и `prop`

Comment: и как быть, подскажите пожалста

Comment: В массиве 3 уровня. Чтоб получить конечное значение с FIELDS надо разобрать его так: `foreach($items[FIELDS ] as $k => $v) {var_dump($v["ID"]);}`

Comment: вы определитесь сначала, в каком виде вам надо вывести данные. `$items['fields'][0]['id']` и `$items['fields'][1]['id']` вам дадут первые два значения. `$items['prop'][0]['domain']['sort']` третье. Если надо выводить в циклах, то очевидно это будет два разных цикла, один для `$items['fields'] as $idx => $v`, второй по аналогии для `prop`

Comment: всем спасибо, разобрался